# Powershell regex to match vhd or vhdx at the end of a string

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm brand new to powershell and I'm trying to write a script to copy files ending in `vhd` or `vhdx`

I can enumerate a directory of files like so:

```
$NEWEST_VHD = Get-ChildItem -Path $vhdSourceDir | Where-Object Name -match ".vhdx?"
```

This will match

```
 foo.vhd
 foo.vhdx
```

However this will also match

```
foo.vhdxxxx
```

How can I write a match that will *only* match files ending in exactly `vhd` or `vhdx` ?

Unsuccessful attempts

```
Where-Object Name -match ".vhdx?" 
Where-Object Name -like ".vhdx?"
Where-Object Name -match ".[vhd]x?" 
Where-Object Name -match ".[vhd]\^x?"
```

Resources I've investigated

http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-regex.html
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730947.aspx
http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 3):

Put a `$` at the end of your pattern:

```
-match ".vhdx?$"
```

`$` in a Regex pattern represents the end of the string.  So, the above will only match `.vhdx?` if it is at the end.  See a demonstration below:

```
PS > 'foo.vhd' -match ".vhdx?$"
True
PS > 'foo.vhdx' -match ".vhdx?$"
True
PS > 'foo.vhdxxxx' -match ".vhdx?$"
False
PS >
```

---

Also, the `.` character has a special meaning in a Regex pattern: it tells PowerShell to match *any* character except a newline.  So, you could experience behavior such as:

```
PS > 'foo.xvhd' -match ".vhdx?$"
True
PS >
```

If this is undesirable, you can add a `\` before the `.`

```
PS > 'foo.xvhd' -match "\.vhdx?$"
False
PS >
```

This tells PowerShell to match a literal period instead.

Comment: Should we not escape the period? you know so we dont match ".xvhdx" files or some such thing. Not that it is likely... but worth understanding.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to check extension, then you can just use `Extension` property instead of `Name`:

```
$NEWEST_VHD = Get-ChildItem -Path $vhdSourceDir | Where-Object Extension -in '.vhd','.vhdx'
```

Answer (score 1):

Mostly just an FYI but there is no need for a regex solution for this particular issue. You could just use a simple filter.

```
$NEWEST_VHD = Get-ChildItem -Path $vhdSourceDir -Filter ".vhd?"
```

Not perfect but if you dont have files called ".vhdz"  then you would be safe. Again, this is not meant as an answer but just useful to know. Reminder that `?` in this case optionally matches a single character but it not regex just a basic file system wildcard.

Depending on how many files you have here you could argue that this would be more efficient since you will get all the files you need off the get go instead of filtering after the fact.